# Any need to use BigDecimal.new method?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

I've seen following code in the [docs for the BigDecimal class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html):

> Similarly:
>
> ```
> (::new(“1.2”) - BigDecimal(“1.0”)) == BigDecimal(“0.2”) -> true
> (1.2 - 1.0) == 0.2 -> false
> ```

So I was wondering if it is neccessary to use the `new` method like this: `BigDecimal.new 2.5, 2`. Or is it just bad practice using just `BigDecimal 2.5, 2`? When evaluating the same BigDecimal value, they all get new references:

```
BigDecimal 2.5, 2
#=> #<BigDecimal:7ffa93e524b0,'0.25E1',18(36)> 
BigDecimal 2.5, 2
#=> #<BigDecimal:7ffa97236600,'0.25E1',18(36)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the latest [kernel doc](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/BigDecimal/instance) we can see that BigDecimal method looks like this:

```
static VALUE
BigDecimal_global_new(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)
{
    return BigDecimal_new(argc, argv, rb_cBigDecimal);
}
```

In other words, `BigDecimal.new` will be called over the supplied arguments. So, yes, it's not strictly necessary to use it explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I also found a shorter way how to init BigDecimals (I have lots of them inside spec-tests).

    `0.01.to_d(2)`

Comment: @loybert Be careful there, since you're starting out with a float, you may already have lost precision before converting to a BigDecimal.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I tried to provocate a numeric error with the minimal example `1.2 - 0.2 == 0.2 # => false`, which would work as `1.2.to_d - 0.2.to_d == 0.2.to_d # => true`. Any other ideas or scenarios, which would fail with my handling? I only use this syntax, when I bring in values into my arithmetics, so a precise calculated BigDecimal will be consistently calculated with other BigDecimals and won't loose it's precision because of the internal typecasted to inprecise float (`#BigDecimal * BigDecimal => BigDecimal`, `#BigDecimal * float => float`).

Comment: @loybert `0.10000000000000001.to_d == BigDecimal.new('0.10000000000000001') #=> false`.

Comment: ah ok, that's a good one! So when initializing high-precision values, I have to do it by string-typed parameter. Thanks